# read.csv lines with no quotes in R

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I am trying to read in a huge csv file from R, but I am having troubles since the elements of the columns that is suppose to be in the string format is not separated by quotes and is creating a new row each time there is a new line. My data is delimited by ~.

For example, my data looks something similar to this:

```
a ~ b ~ c ~ d ~ e
1 ~ name1 ~ This is a paragraph. 

This is a second paragraph.

~ num1 ~ num2 ~

2 ~ name2 ~ This is an new set of paragraph.

~ num1 ~ num2 ~
```

I hope to get something like this:

```
a |      b     |         c                                        |  d     |   e   |
____________________________________________________________________________________
1 |    name1  | This is a paragraph. This is a second paragraph.  |  num1  | num2  |

2 |    name2  | This is a new set of paragraph.                   |  num1  | num2  |
```

But I end up with something ugly like this:

```
a                          |    b    |         c               |  d     |   e   |
__________________________________________________________________________________
1                          |  name1  |   This is a paragraph.  |        |       |

This is a second paragraph |         |                         |        |       |
                           |  num1   |        num2
2                          |  name2  | This is a new set of paragraph. | num1 | num2  |
```

I tried to set allowEscapes = TRUE in read.csv but that didn't do the trick. My input currently looks like this:

```
read.csv(filename, header = T, sep = '~', stringAsFactors = F, fileEncoding = "latin1", quote = "", strip.white = TRUE)
```

My next idea is to insert a quotation after each ~, but I am hoping to see if there are better methods.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the sample data

Comment: Every row ends with `~`, am I right?

Comment: @Metrics: I can't really provide the sample data because 1) it's big and messy, 2) I am obtaining it through my supervisor's database and can't really copy and paste the data. But this example should be close to the data

Comment: @zero323: yes, each row ends with ~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this for example :

```
ll = readLines(textConnection('a ~ b ~ c ~ d ~ e
1 ~ name1 ~ This is a paragraph. 
This is a second paragraph.
~ num1 ~ num2 ~
2 ~ name2 ~ This is an new set of paragraph.
~ num1 ~ num2 ~'))
## each line begin with a numeric followed by a space
## I use this pattern to sperate lines
llines <- split(ll[-1],cumsum(grepl('^[0-9] ',ll[-1])))
## add the header to the splitted and concatenated lines 
read.table(text=unlist(c(ll[1],lapply(llines,paste,collapse=''))),
           sep='~',header=TRUE)


         a                                                 b      c      d  e
1   name1   This is a paragraph. This is a second paragraph.  num1   num2  NA
2   name2                   This is an new set of paragraph.  num1   num2  NA
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this method tomorrow and tell you how it works as seeing how my supervisor turned off her computer for the day so I can't access the data.

Comment: "when I run a fraction of the document I have to parse" I get the following error: more columns than column names

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach in R that depends on (1) `~` being a true delimiter that doesn't appear in any of your paragraphs and (2) `~` appearing at the end of each record.

But first, some sample data (in a way that others can also reproduce your problem).

```
cat("a ~ b ~ c ~ d ~ e",
    "1 ~ name1 ~ This is a paragraph.",
    "",
    "This is a second paragraph.",
    "",
    "~ num1 ~ num2 ~",
    "",
    "2 ~ name2 ~ This is an new set of paragraph.",
    "",
    "~ num1 ~ num2 ~", sep = "\n", file = "test.txt")
```

We'll start with `readLines` to get the data in. We'll also add a `~` at the end of the header row.

```
x <- readLines("test.txt")
x[1] <- paste(x[1], "~") ## Add a ~ at the end of the first line
```

Now, we'll `paste` everything into a nice long string.

```
y <- paste(x, collapse = " ")
```

Use `scan` to quickly "read" the data again, but instead of using the `file` argument, we'll use the `text` argument and refer to the "y" object we just created. Since the last line ends with a `~` there will be an extra `""` at the end, which we will remove before proceeding.

```
z <- scan(text = y, what = character(), sep = "~", strip.white = TRUE)
# Read 16 items
z <- z[-length(z)]
```

Since we now have a character vector, we can easily convert this to a `matrix`, and then to a `data.frame`. We know the `colnames` are the first 5 values, so we'll drop those when creating the `matrix`, and reinsert them as the names of the `data.frame`.

```
df <- setNames(data.frame(
  matrix(z[6:length(z)], ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)), z[1:5])
df
#   a     b                                                 c    d    e
# 1 1 name1 This is a paragraph.  This is a second paragraph. num1 num2
# 2 2 name2                  This is an new set of paragraph. num1 num2
```

Answer (score 0):

When I saw this was a text-processing problem, I decided Python would be much easier. Apologies if you aren't familiar with it or don't have access to it:

```
import csv

all_rows = []
with open('tilded_csv.txt') as in_file:
    header_line = next(in_file)
    header = header_line.strip().split('~')
    current_record = []
    for line in in_file:
        # Assume that a number at the start of a line
        # signals a new record
        if line[0].isdigit():
            new_record = line.strip()
            if current_record:
                all_rows.append(current_record.split('~'))
            current_record = line.strip()
        else:
            current_record += line.strip()
# Add the last record
all_rows.append(current_record.split('~'))

with open('standard_csv.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    out_csv = csv.writer(out_file, dialect='excel')
    out_csv.writerow(header)
    for row in all_rows:
        out_csv.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Actually my preferred language is python, but I have already imported other files that I need to export to a database (postgresql) using R, so I figured I should stick with a standard language for this task. Worst case scenario is to use python. But thanks for the tip.